# WCF Error Types cannot be registered with service open

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

Currently we have an application that has a server application that exposes a WCF REST service and then we have the client side that communicates with the WCF REST services on the server. Currently I'm getting an error on the client side that I cannot figure out and am having no luck in Google finding answers.

As soon as I make the call from the ChannelFactory to create channel the following exception is thrown. Does anybody know what this error means and where I might find something that could help me resolve the issue? Below is also the generic method we use for calling the service from the client side. Fiddler doesn't show any communication coming out of the client so the issue is directly on the client side. The server and the client both share the same interface for communication.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=New types cannot be registered with serializer manager after the service has been opened.
  Source=System.ServiceModel.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UnwrappedTypesXmlSerializerManager.RegisterType(Object key, IList`1 types)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterXmlSerializerMessageFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription operation, Type parameterType, Boolean isRequestFormatter, XmlSerializerOperationBehavior xsob, UnwrappedTypesXmlSerializerManager serializerManager)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.CreateXmlFormatter(OperationDescription operation, Type type, Boolean isRequestFormatter, UnwrappedTypesXmlSerializerManager xmlSerializerManager)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.CreateClientFormatter(OperationDescription operation, Type type, Boolean isRequestFormatter, Boolean useJson, UnwrappedTypesXmlSerializerManager xmlSerializerManager)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7.<>c__DisplayClassa.<GetRequestClientFormatter>b__4()
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetRequestClientFormatter>b__3()
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.HideReplyMessage(OperationDescription operationDescription, Effect effect)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetRequestClientFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
       at Enterprise.ServiceModel.ChannelFactoryExtensions.ExecuteRequest[TChannel,TResult](ChannelFactory`1 factory, Func`2 readDelegate) in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Enterprise.Common\ServiceModel\ChannelFactoryExtensions.cs:line 115
       at Foo.Service.Client.FooDataMessenger.RetrieveAircraft() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Service.Client\Client\FooDataMessenger.cs:line 699
       at Foo.Service.Client.FooDataMessenger.<ReadAircraft>b__3() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Service.Client\Client\FooDataMessenger.cs:line 95
       at Enterprise.DelegateHelpers.ElapsedFunc[TOut](Func`1 actionDelegate, TOut& result) in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Enterprise.Common\Extensions\DelegateHelpers.cs:line 103
       at Enterprise.DelegateHelpers.ElapsedFuncTrace[TOut](Func`1 actionDelegate, String location, String method, String action) in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Enterprise.Common\Extensions\DelegateHelpers.cs:line 128
       at Foo.Service.Client.FooDataMessenger.ReadAircraft() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Service.Client\Client\FooDataMessenger.cs:line 91
       at Foo.Service.FooServiceClientData.ReadAircraft() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Service.Client\FooServiceClientData.cs:line 215
       at Foo.Config.Data.InternalDatumController.get_Aircraft() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Config.Data\InternalDatumController.cs:line 90
       at Foo.Config.Data.Sync.AircraftDefsSyncView.ReadData() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Config.Data\Sync\FooData\AircraftDefsSyncView.cs:line 81
       at Foo.Synchronization.Databases.Base.SyncProvider.ReadViewData(String viewName, Int32 batchCount) in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Synchronization\Databases\Base\SyncProvider.cs:line 88
       at Foo.Synchronization.Databases.Base.SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Synchronization\Databases\Base\SyncOrchestrator.cs:line 114
       at Foo.Synchronization.Plugin.Synchronizer.Synchronize_FooData() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Synchronization.Plugin\Synchronizer.cs:line 201
       at Foo.Synchronization.Plugin.Synchronizer.Sync() in C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\Foo_TFS\Foo 5.1\Trunk\Foo.Synchronization.Plugin\Synchronizer.cs:line 91
  InnerException:
```

Generic Method

```
public static TResult ExecuteRequest<TChannel, TResult>(
                     this ChannelFactory<TChannel> factory,
                     Func<TChannel, TResult> readDelegate)
{
    if (factory == null || readDelegate == null)
    {
        return default(TResult);
    }

    TChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();
#if DEBUG
    // Changes the timeout to 10 minutes so you can step through server
    // code if you need to without getting a timeout error.
    ((IClientChannel)channel).OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
#endif
    TResult result;
    try
    {
        result = readDelegate(channel);
    }
    finally
    {
        var client = (IClientChannel)channel;
        if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            client.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            client.Close();
        }

        client.DisposeSafe();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you may have a type mismatch between TResult and the actual type returned by the delegate you're sending. That's a pretty unusual WCF exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem lies in the Generic Method posted. For some reason because there is only the delegate being executed in the try/finally statement that the finally was never being executed. The fix to the method is to move the close inside the try with the delegate code and just dispose the channel in the finally. Below is the corrected generic method.

```
public static TResult ExecuteRequest<TChannel, TResult>(
                                                           this ChannelFactory<TChannel> factory,
                                                           Func<TChannel, TResult> readDelegate)
    {
        if (factory == null || readDelegate == null)
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }

        TChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();
#if DEBUG
        // Changes the timeout to 10 minutes so you can step through server
        // code if you need to without getting a timeout error.
        ((IClientChannel)channel).OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
#endif
        TResult result;
        try
        {
            result = readDelegate(channel);
            var client = (IClientChannel)channel;
            CommunicationState state = client.State;
            if (state != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ((IClientChannel)channel).Abort();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            ((IClientChannel)channel).DisposeSafe();
        }

        return result;
    }
```